# Unable to mock a method with constant default param

Tags: php, phpunit

I have the following code in a test method:

```
$container = $this
    ->getMockBuilder(ContainerInterface::class)
    ->getMock();

$container->method('get')
    ->will($this->returnValueMap([
        ['a', 'b'],
        ['c', 'd']
    ]));

var_dump($container->get('a'));

exit;
```

I'm simply trying to create a stub (based on an interface). But this returns `NULL`. However, if I change the method from `get` to `has` it does work (returns `b`).

The difference between the signatures is as follows:

```
public function get($id, $invalidBehavior = self::EXCEPTION_ON_INVALID_REFERENCE);

public function has($id);
```

Why is it not working and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not supported by PHPUnit to take into consideration default parameters.

So you need to change this:

```
$container->method('get')
    ->will($this->returnValueMap([
        ['a', 'b'],
        ['c', 'd']
    ]));
```

into this:

```
$container->method('get')
    ->will($this->returnValueMap([
        ['a', 1, 'b'],
        ['c', 1, 'd']
    ]));
```

Hope this help